# Info log at Glassfish 4

Tags: java, sql-server, glassfish, ejb

I am developing an EJB Application which needs to query an sql server db every 10 seconds o get some data.

I notice that in log i have these two lines:

```
INFO:   RAR7114: Unable to get ClientInfo for connection 
INFO:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
```

Although the applications works perfectly without any problem i would like to undesrtand why i receive this info every time i query my DB.

Below is the software i use in this application:

I use netbeans 7.3.1
Sql Server 2012
Java 6
jtds 1.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is a hint that either the DB server or the corresponding driver doesn't support the method `setClientInfo`. It seems that this method is called everytime a connection is closed.

This behaviour is described in [GLASSFISH-17061](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17061) and according to that it should be fixed in Glassfish 4.0 and 3.1.2.2 but some of the comments seem to show that it still can occur. You may try a different JDBC driver (if there is any).

Comment: thank you for the answer. i have reached that conclusion after searching a bit in net but i needed an confirmation of that.
thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I am also seeing this behavior on Glassfish v4 using the jTDS driver.

I'm curious which project will address this item. Maybe it will be the jTDS folks. Maybe it will be the Glassfish folks. But, in the mean time here is how one can update/change the Glassfish Log Levels:

http://gesker.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/jtds-glassfish-v4-rar7114-rar7114/

The relevant parts from the link:

> - Admin Console (YourServer:4848),
> - Click on *Configurations*,
> - Click on *server-config*,
> - Click on *Logger Settings*,
> - Click on *Log Levels*,
> - Click *Add Logger*
>
> and enter: `javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.spi` into the new *Logger Name* field and change the *Log Level* to `WARNING`.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the relevant parts from the link, so others won't need to look at it as I did :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem moving upgrading my MySQL driver (from 5.1.3 to 5.1.34) through maven central. I started seeing this problem after upgrading MySQL. Maybe this is something to do with some API changes in the newer version of MySQL which the older connector driver does not have.